# Why won't this PHP/SQL create the table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

```
<?php
try {
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
  $sql = $DBH->exec("
    CREATE TABLE `store_config` (
    store_name varchar(30),
    last_update date)
    ");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Could not connect to database.";
  $DBH = null;
}
?>
```

The PDOException is not thrown, there is probably an SQL error but I don't know how to retrieve that error and when I check the database with phpMyAdmin there are no tables created. What did I do wrong?

Thanks for reading.

**EDIT:**
When I executed the same SQL code directly into phpMyAdmin it gave permission denied error...

## 1142 - CREATE command denied to user '$user'@'$my_ip' for table 'store_config'

I am confused because when I created the user with the web hosts web form it didn't give me options to grant any permissions but only to make this user the database owner - is that what I have to do?

**EDIT:**

## I gave my user account 'DBO access' and it works now (the table is created).

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: The SQL works if you just put it into MySQL, so it must be either it's not connecting or your dbname isn't the name of an actual DB on MySQL or that user doesn't have the rights to the DB.

Comment: @thezboe please see the edit in my post - I have an error now (permission denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It should get you the error you're looking for that will tell you whats going on.

```
<?php
try {
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
  $sql = $DBH->exec("
    CREATE TABLE `store_config` (
    store_name varchar(30),
    last_update date)
    ") or die(print_r($DBH->errorInfo(), true));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Could not connect to database.";
  $DBH = null;
}
?>
```

Comment: +1 for the `$DBH->errorInfo()`, thanks. @NathanielFord please see the updated question with the error

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a way to grant the create permission to your user from the machine you're running the code from. The user probably only has permissions from localhost, so you'd have to upload the code to the server and run it there to have permission.

Comment: Actually you probably don't need to prepare it. Just usually the way I do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that but it still wont create any table.